# get current lat and long in android map

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi there I try find my location via GPS or Network:

```
double latitude;
double longitude;

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
           mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            latitude = ?;
            longitude = ?
    } else {
        latitude = -34;
        longitude = 151;
    }

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

I read some article,some suggest use this:

```
mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude();
```

But it's a depricated function and also not work.

Comment: As suggested by Android reference, you should use FusedLocationProviderApi, so you need to connect to Location Services and ask for location updates in order to get current location.

Comment: Another possibility is using listener mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(). This gives you location updates on map. Unfortunately this method is also deprecated and Android reference suggests even in this case to refer to FusedLocationProviderApi.

Comment: @thetonrifles your not completely wrong, but that's not needed here and it would be way too complicated to achieve this simple task  :)

Comment: @thetonrifles, thanks for your new information (for me), I read now some about FusedLocationProviderApi.

Comment: You have two options to achieve this, the first one is through FusedLocationProvider, refer to this documentation on [Displaying a Location Address](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html#connect) and the other is through [Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation#DetectingUserLocation), but this has a disadvantage as stated in the documentation "Note that geolocation is a device-specific API; some browser/devices support it, while others do not (or cannot), so you cannot assume that geolocation is always possible for a web application."

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will get your the idea.

```
private LatLng mUserPosition;

...

mUserPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
drawUserMarkerAndCircle(mUserPosition.latitude, mUserPosition.longitude);
```